# Add protocol to inputted URL in a user-friendly way

Tags: html

I'm trying to make a text input for an external link so that I can make an anchor tag that can navigate somewhere to.

```html
<a href="www.bing.com"          target="_blank">URL WITHOUT protocol</a>
<a href="https://www.bing.com"  target="_blank">URL WITH protocol</a>
```

But when people naturally type 'www.bing.com', I get a URL without protocol, which works like navigating on the current site.

I can make a regex pattern asking the user to input an absolute link (prefixed with protocol, such as 'http://....' or 'https://...'), but is there a more user-friendly way to fix the problem?

Comment: If you can detect a missing protocol, you can add it automatically, right?

Comment: You can print `https://` in front of the input field, so people know they don't have to type the protocol - then you always add it yourself. Accidentally typing the protocol can be filtered away.

Comment: @PeterKrebs the problem is I don't know the protocal is HTTP or HTTPS

Comment: Well then have it be a select box with `https` being the default and another `http` option. http shouldn't be trusted though, hope that's not used anymore.